# Python - handle time between 2 and 26

Tags: python

I have dataset where I have time column between 2:00:00 and 26:00:00. I want to convert it to time beetween 0 and 23.
Here is example of data:

[image]

The data type is string. I would like to subtract 3 from these rows, but I don't know how to do it in Python.

Comment: Do you mean between 2 and 26? Your sample has time below 3!

Comment: Yes, thanks, I edited this question. Still don't know how to handle this problem.

Comment: Each time is 3 hours greater

Comment: Do you only want to know how to convert a String with this structure :"HH:MM:SS"? Or do you want to know the hole process of reading it out of a file and writing it again into one?

Comment: Because of out of range hours like 25 I couldn't convert them into time format.

Comment: `[str(int(x[:2]) - 2).zfill(2) + x[2:] for x in dates]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be a bit overkill for your purposes, but I quite like using `arrow` for date manipulation. This is how it can be adapted to work with time:

```
import arrow

def func(t):
    # Split the time str into integers
    hours, minutes, seconds = map(int, t.split(':'))

    # Make a temp arrow object
    a = arrow.get()
    
    # Set the exact time on the arrow object
    replaced = a.replace(hour=hours%24, minute=minutes, second=seconds)

    # Remove 2 hours from the result
    shifted = replaced.shift(hours=-2)

    # Get the new time
    return shifted.format('HH:mm:ss')
```

Results:

```
>>> func('25:49:34')
23:49:34

>>> func('02:57:49')
00:57:49
```

I'm assuming you mean to subtract 2 hours, but if not, just change the 2 to 3.

Alternatively, here is a very simple solution with the same output:

```
':'.join(part if i else str((int(part)-2)%24).zfill(2) for i, part in enumerate(t.split(':')))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have consistent data you could edit the time as a string, then convert it to a time. Something like this:

```
import datetime

original_time_string = "25:49:34"
hour = int(original_time_string[:2])
new_time_string = "{}{}".format(hour-3,original_time_string[2:])
new_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(new_time_string,"%H:%M:%S").time()
```

Honestly I don't get why you want to subtrac 3. Shouldn't it be 2?

```
print (new_time)
>22:49:34
```